# How should I approach or shouldn't unit test?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I have a huge codebase written by someone else its not unit tested at all. I want to add unit testing to a spring application.but the code is very much of decoupled and some times the code is not testable. how should I approach this should I start with the low level objects or the high level once and can you give me a step by step example of how to write unit tests for a spring application.

Comment: Decoupled code is easier to test, not harder. Too broad and unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I want to test a spring class which has some autowired dependencies and those also have some autowired in them some dependencies uses database while others uses config files how should I test and mock these classes.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily transform `@Autowired` attributes into `@Autowired` constructors. Check this example:

```
@Component
public class SomeClass {
    @Autowired
    private SomeDependency someDependency;

    public ... doSomething(...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

can be transformed to

```
@Component
public class SomeClass {

    private SomeDependency someDependency;

    @Autowired
    public SomeClass(SomeDependency someDependency) {
        this.someDependency = someDependency;
    }

    public ... doSomething(...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

In fact, this injection method is preferred since your object has **all** the dependencies it needs when the constructor finishes. In the first approach you would need to do something like:

```
SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
someClass.setSomeDependency(someDependency); // <- you would need to add this
```

Also this could happen!

```
SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
someClass.methodThatUsesSomeDependency(); // <- NullPointerException since someDependency is not initialized!
```

So, by using constructor injection you are safe! You could also add a bit of extra safety by setting your dependencies as final so they **must** be initialized when the constructor ends:

```
@Component
public class SomeClass {

    private final SomeDependency someDependency;

    @Autowired
    public SomeClass(SomeDependency someDependency) {
        // Removing this line will cause a compile time error
        this.someDependency = someDependency;
    }

    public ... doSomething(...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

So, summing up: move your `@Autowired` annotation to a constructor and everything will go fine.

Once you have a constructor with its dependencies as arguments unit testing it should be trivial

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to the [Integration Testing provided by Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html)

Here below is an example JUnit test class that provides test cases on beans in Spring Context.

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/your-spring-cfg.xml" })
public class YourTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests
{
    @Autowired
    private YourBean beanToTest;

    @Test
    public void testYourBean()
    {
        beanToTest.method();
        ....
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

For configuration classes, you may refer to the following code.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes=YourConfigClass.class, loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class YourTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests
{
    @Autowired
    private YourBean beanToTest;

    @Test
    public void testYourBean()
    {
        beanToTest.method();
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: One question here do you use xml configuration in real world project.?

Comment: Yes, the project I'm working with is still using xml configuration and compose unit test classes like what I answered. BTW, you may refer to [link](http://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles/) if you are using configuration classes.